# Why is the disk usage on the Hetzner storage box less than on the Hetzner dedicated server?

Tags: devops, storage

I'm using the Hetzner storage box to backup some data from my Hetzner dedicated server.

After rsync'ing 66gb worth of data from the server to the box, the box now shows only 24gb used (both calculated using `du -sh <folder>`).

Does anyone know why this happens? Was all the data actually sent to the box, or does hetzner compress the data in the storage boxes in some way?

Answer (score 1):

I have just been surprised by the same behaviour myself.

I can't find *any* information in the Hetzner docs about built-in compression for files uploaded to their 'Storage Box' service, but I'm seeing pretty unambiguous evidence that the boxes are indeed compressing files:

I have several SQL backup files in a particular box; some are compressed with `xz` and others are uncompressed. The files with xz compression show identical sizes when using `ls -lh` and `du -h`, while the files without compression are considerably smaller with `du -h` than `ls -lh`.

The compression is clearly very light though, as I guess you'd expect: a typical instance of the (very compressible) SQL dump files weighs in at 9 GiB, while the Hetzner box reports 4.1 GiB of storage used for that file. By comparison, the same file when compressed with `xz -1 -T 12` is only 2.2 GiB, and the '-1' parameter to `xz` sets it to pretty fast & light compression (though '-0' is faster still).

(I should add that I was paranoid enough to do some checksums, to prove to myself that the files on the box were identical to the source files!)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me which files you are trying to put on your StorageBox ?

Had the same problem today and I saved .img and .qcow2 files on the Storagebox (Out of 360Gb i got 92 on the Storagebox)

I figured, that the Storagebox does not assigned the Null spaces, so the files are much smaller. So maybe try downloading the data back to your device, it should have the 66gb worth of data again.

Hopefully this explanation can help you ^^